# The notification isn't showing in the telephone after i press the button

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've written the code below, and allegedly, according to what I read it's suppose to show the notification right after i press the button, but the notification doesn't pop up.
Can someone please explain to me why?
Thank you.
I've added below the code of the activity an the layout.

this is the Activity

```
namespace PresentationNoti
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        Button btn1, btn2;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            btn1 = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.btn1);
            btn2 = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.btn2);
            btn1.Click += Btn1_Click;
            btn2.Click += Btn2_Click;
        }

        private void Btn2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            mBuilder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.birthday);
            mBuilder.SetContentTitle("It's your birthday");
            mBuilder.SetContentText("Happy B-day Birthday Boy/Girl");
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);
            stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MainActivity)));
            // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
            stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, (int)PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
            mBuilder.SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            mNotificationManager.Notify(0, mBuilder.Build());
        }

        private void Btn1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            mBuilder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.birthday);
            mBuilder.SetContentTitle("It's your birthday");
            mBuilder.SetContentText("Happy B-day Birthday Boy/Girl");
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            mNotificationManager.Notify(0, mBuilder.Build());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the axml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#90aacc">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="basic notification"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="advanced notification"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is the Buttons registered?  The click methods are events and you need to add the button events for the buttons to work.

Comment: Yes, they are registered.

Comment: I thought that maybe I need to add something to the manifest. Do you know if I should?

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the code of buttons please?

Comment: If you add a DisplayAlert() in your button's click method, does it get triggered? (I'm assuming that you're working with Xamarin. Let me know if that's not the case)

Comment: Yes, I'm working with Xamarin. In adittion it gets triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Xamarin's docs, you should create a notification channel (API >= 26) and use following code to launch the notification:

```
var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.Build());
```

Edit: Create notifications channel if you're compiling for API 26 or above (mandatory in that case).

P.S: Full xamarin's android notifications docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications-walkthrough)

Comment: Hey, I used the channel and it worked. thank you very much for the help and for the guide.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad that it helped you! ^^

Remember to mark the answer as accepted as it will help others with the same problem to identify the solution quicker.

Happy coding and welcome to stackoverflow!